# Dir folder, sub folders and files excluding specific files in folders

Tags: windows, cmd

Just a question, is possible to use dir to list everything but the content of some folders? I have a backup external 4TB HDD with Protools audio sessions, I would like to save a list for offline search, I know I can use

```
dir /s > file_list.txt
```

but as there are some folders with a huge amount of files that I don't need to list. By example a single session "Audio Files" folder can have more than 1000 files, making the list to big. I would like to have everything listed but the content of "Audio Files", though i would like to have the folder "Audio Files" listed but not its contents.

I tried:

```
dir /s "H:\backup" | findstr /v "\Audio Files"
```

and that exclude the "Audio Files" folder from the list, as man says /v:

> Prints only lines that do not contain a match.

```
tree /a /f
```

Looks nice but i cant use any other switch I think.

There is any way to achieve this? I know that there are 3rd party tools like this ones:

[10 Free Tools To Save or Print a List of File and Folder Contents](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/print-all-file-and-folder-contents-to-text-or-printer/2/)

but I would like to avoid to install 3rd party apps.

Comment: Are you specifically looking to use the cmd prompt? Or is powershell an option?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `findstr` more than once

```
dir /s  "H:\backup" | findstr /v "\Audio Files" | findstr /v "\excluded-Folder2" | findstr /v "\excluded-Folder3"
```